# Google Chrome New Tab position issues

Tags: google-chrome

I've had a process of working which involves opening a large number of new tabs from a single page that is reloaded with new data before each opening. For example, I had the following setup:

1-2-3
I copy an ID from 1 into 2 and then after that ID's account is loaded in 2, I open its order - A.
Then I copy another ID from 1 into 2 and repeat the action with that order now being B.

So far for years, the actual order of actions has always lead to a result of the following tabs being opened:

1-2-A-B-3

Now, since a week or so, Google Chrome is acting up weird and is opening them in the following order:

1-2-B-A-3

Putting B on the left of A instead of the right which is kinda annoying when you open A-B-C-D-E-F and you have been doing this entire thing in that order for the last 5 years.

- Note that Chrome is still opening tabs from 2 in the correct order if 2 hasn't been reloaded with new data, but that is not my issue.

I reset chrome's settings and flushed all browser data but the issue persists. Friends tried this and it is not working like that for them. If anyone has an idea how to fix this, please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you wish to control the position if the new tab.
I don't really understand what you mean, and I don't know what has
changed on your computer, but you may use an extension to control
the placement of the new tab.

Try the extension
[Tab Position Options](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-options/fjccjnfkdkdmjohojoggodkigkjkkjhl/related?hl=en) :

[image]